# Using files from HDFS into Apache Spark

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have few files in my hdfs and I want to use them in Spark. I am able to see my files when I give the following command:

```
bin/hadoop dfs -ls /input
```

How should I give the path of this file in spark to create an RDD:

```
val input=sc.textFile("???")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Spark installation is properly configured, then your normal HDFS paths should just work verbatim unchanged in Spark as well:

```
val input = sc.textFile("/input")
```

If that's not working then you probably need to make sure your Spark configuration is [properly picking up your Hadoop conf dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286954/spark-job-fails-because-it-cant-find-the-hadoop-core-site-xml).

You might also want to try directly checking your file listings from your Spark code to make sure the configurations are getting imported properly:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val path = new Path("/input")
path.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).listStatus(path)
```

Comment: I get the error Input path does not exist. I am not able to figure out how to give path of input file which is created in hdfs.